# How do I iterate over DataFrame Groupby after applying size()?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Combing thru log files I build a dataframe of the process that failed, the date and the machine.  My goal is to provide a bar chart for each process where the dates are the x-axis and the count of failures each day is computed with .size().

```
grouped = fail_df.groupby(['Process', 'Date']).size
print(fail_df.groupby(['Process', 'Date']).size())
```

shows exactly what I want. First lines of the print are

```
Process          Date
10HzTail         2019-06-16     1
1553Prox         2019-06-16     3
                 2019-06-17     8
                 2019-06-18    10
                 2019-06-19     2
                 2019-06-20     5
Cthread2         2019-06-18     1
                 2019-06-20     1
```

I try to iterate as

```
for name, row in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(row)
```

Gives this error output

```
dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./allpandas", line 140, in <module>
main()
 File "./allpandas", line 125, in main
  for name, row in grouped:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I would want to process each Process in turn.  I want the dates and count fed to the bar chart for that Process.

Is there a way to iterate over this or have I made a fundamental mistake in my grouping?

*UPDATE*

I tried the suggested size() and still get the same error.

```
grouped = fail_df.groupby(['Process', 'Date']).size()
for name, row in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(row)
```

Are there other suggestions?

Comment: I think you just need brackets after size. fail_df.groupby(['Process', 'Date']).size()     When you don't have brackets I believe you get one integer for total size.

Comment: I tried the suggested size() and get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fastest solution if you are using matplotlib

Are you using `matplotlib`?
If so, if I understood what you want, you don't need to loop, you can use [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) which does all the job for you.

```
grouped = fail_df.groupby(['Process', 'Date']).size()
axis = grouped.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Where `plt` is the usual `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

You may need to fix the label at the bottom of each bar, if they are too large.

#### Your error

Your error comes from the fact that `grouped` is a `Series` and not a `DataFrame`, so you cannot iterate over it that way. Iterating over a series returns only the value. You should do:

```
for value in grouped:
    print(value)
```

to see the sizes, but you lose the index label. To get also the index label the solution is:

```
for name, row in zip(grouped.index, grouped):
    print(name)
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I found a solution using agg('count') and creating another pandas column to hold the answer.   Then applying groupby again let me iterate and generate plots one by one with dates on the x-axis, individual titles etc.